# Generic specialization base constructor calls wrong method

Tags: c#, generics

```
class Base<T1, T2>
{
    protected Base(T1 type1, T2 type2)
    {
    }
}

public class Derived<T> : Base<T, int>
{
    public Derived(T type1, int i)
        : base(type1, i)
    {
    }
}

public class Derived<T> : Base<T, double>
{
    public Derived(T type1, double d)
        :base(type1, d)
    {
    }
}
```

My code above fails to compile as Visual Studio flags the second derived type's constructor's base call as 'MyBase.MyBase(T, int)', where I would expect this to actually be calling 'MyBase.MyBase(T, double)'.

Removing or renaming (i.e. to DerivedInt) the first derived type allows the second derived type to compile correctly.

My question is, why is this happening?
I am genuinely unsure as to what is causing this behavior? How does the first derivative type seem to conflict with the second?
Is there, apart from the aforementioned renaming, a way to fix this? Or perhaps a better way to approach this problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two types called `Derived<T>` in the same namespace. This isn't allowed.

The fact that they have different base classes doesn't mean that they have different names.

If you were to write `typeof(Derived<string>)` which one would you pick?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you can't have two types with the same name (i.e., `Derived<T>`) under the same namespace. That's why renaming one of them makes it work.

Comment: Actually the name is ``Derived`1``. For the purpose of distinguishing types, the names of the type parameters don't matter, only their number. Generic parameter constraints also don't matter.